# Kubernetes Cluster Master Node on Windows OS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I'm new on Kubernetes and currently following this guide: [Deploy Kubernetes cluster for Windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-windows-walkthrough). I recently noticed that the VM provisioned as master node is on Linux, my question is, "Is it possible to use Windows as a Kubernetes Cluster master node?".

My project requires to use Windows OS on physical servers, so Linux as OS for Kubernetes master node might not be good option for container orchestrator and I will need to use Docker Swarm instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation you can’t use Windows as a Kubernetes master.
From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/creating-a-linux-master):

> A recently-updated Linux machine is required to follow along;
>   Kubernetes master resources like [kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/), [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/), and
>   [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) have not been ported to Windows yet.

Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/#setting-up-windows-server-containers-on-kubernetes) also implies that you need to have Linux master node.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Yes I've also read that but as a novice in Kubernetes and followed the link I've given above, it is miss-able information.

Comment: @jravenger4, I've submitted an edit to getslaf's answer. The Microsoft link updated their wording which makes the situation much more clear. There are several Kubernetes pieces required for a master which do not yet have Windows equivalents.